# c# system.drawing how to print pdf to whole page size without blurr and losing quality

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, system.drawing, printdocument

I made a windows service that's runs in background service and listening for web app to order to print.
the web app send a pdf file and width and height of the printer paper with count of copies
I wrote the code this way

convert pdf to image

```cs
public Image ConverPdfToImage(IFormFile pdfFile)
    {
        if (pdfFile == null || pdfFile.Length==0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var documemt = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument();
      
        documemt.LoadFromStream(pdfFile.OpenReadStream());

        Image image = documemt.SaveAsImage(0,PdfImageType.Bitmap);
      
        return image;
    }
```

then the event handler

```cs
 private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev,Image img)
    {
       
       
        Rectangle pageBounds = ev.PageBounds;
        int x = pageBounds.Left - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX;
        int y = pageBounds.Top - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY;
        int width = pageBounds.Width;
        int height = pageBounds.Height;
        
        ev.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        ev.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        ev.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        ev.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

     
       local = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, local);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, local);
   }
```

and the final function that prints

```cs
            PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = form.Printer;
             printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = form.Landscape;
         
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies = form.Count;

           
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =GetPaperSize(form.Width, form.Height);
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            
            
            Image img = ConverPdfToImage(form.PrintFile);
        
           
            printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, args) => this.PrintPage(sender,args,img);
          
            
            printDocument.Print();
```

the printDocument is from System.Drawing

It makes correct size in printer
printer are for lables and they have label papers with custom size

but the printed paper is blur and hard to read
some of it is so messed up and dirty

glad to help me make print sharp and good quality

Comment: You are printing an image and resizing a bitmap will result in what you see. Your pdf library that you are using hopefully has a printing method to directly print the pdf.

Comment: it does not print in correct speed and correct size so it made me use    ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, local);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, local);  to draw in correct size